# Dynamic display the contents of ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, dynamic-data, android-scrollview

What I am trying to achieve is that, I am having an `ArrayList< String > data = new ArrayList< String >();` that contains values form 1 to 100. Now if I want to display this data in a scrollView then I will write the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {
    View v = getLayoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.mycontainer, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText(data.get(i));
    layout.addView(v);
}
```

The above code will display the data, but it may take some time to display all the data. What I want to do is that, I want to update the scrollView at every loop and display each row after  the textview is added to the layout.

Please check out [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard) for the reference.

This is the test code that I am doing to achieve what I want. Please have a look:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    adapter.setData(String.valueOf(i));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Code for my ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private int count;
private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public ListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void setData(String str) {
    data.add(str);
    count = data.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();          
        holder.tv = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {
        for(int i=0; i<=data.size(); i++) {
            holder.tv.setText(data.get(i));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance
Abhishek

Comment: Why don't you use a `ListView` that automatically does this for you (re-uses views and it adds view as the user scrolls), instead of using a ScrollView and populating it with such a big number of views?

Comment: The view that I am talking about is in the application clean master https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard the way this app loads the data I want the same thing

Comment: Instead of dynamically creating textview you can have a listview which will dynamically add all your values.just set an adapter to the list view

Comment: At a first look there are a combination of ListView and ExpandableListView

Comment: I have also used listview but i am not able to achieve what this app has done https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard please look at the technique how it loads the data of apps

Comment: You are creating a textview of same id every time, create the text view dynamically through code like Textview view= new Text view(this). I guess this will help

Comment: @gunar yes but i am not able to figure out how they are displaying data of single cell instead of showing data of all the cell's at once

Comment: @Ritaban yes the id's will be same because i am adding same cells to the scrollview

Comment: If you want to get the value/id of different text views which are created dynamically , you can set id for different text views like TV.setid("text view"+i) inside the loop and later you can do findviewbyid.you can also achieve this by using settag()/findviewbytag() method. Sorry the answer is not formatted as I am typing thru mobile

Comment: @Ritaban you are not getting what i want. Please check out this app and then you may get what i want https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard

Comment: Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: @Ritaban TextView.setId(int) takes an integer argument. What you are supplying in `TV.setid("text view"+i)` is a String. That, anyways, won't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Yeah it will be settag instead.thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

> Clean Master (Cleaner)

What this app is using is a regular ListView.

> I am not able to figure out how they are displaying data of single
>   cell instead of showing data of all the cell's at once

What this app is doing:

The apps objects are fetched at run-time. These app objects are passed to the adapter one by one (as opposed to passing them as one long list), as they are made available, and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is called after adding each object.

Comment: I have tried your method and passed the data one by one to BaseAdapter but it was of no use. It still loads the entire data not one by one.

Comment: @Abhishek Can you post your adapter's and activity's code in the question above and leave me a message? I'll take a look at it. Thanks.